# Can we create domain project for cloudhub applications in Mulesoft? if not, why?

Tags: mule, mule-component, mule-esb, mulesoft

I have seen articles explaining about shared-resources only for mule standalone servers. But, technically I want to know the reason why we can't deploy a domain project and reuse the resources for other applications in cloudhub. Can you please help me know this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mule applications in CloudHub are deployed into their own Mule Runtime, separate from any other applications. ie there is only one application per runtime. It would not be possible to use a domain to share anything, because domains can only share resources in the same runtime. That's the reason CloudHub doesn't allow to deploy domains. It just doesn't make sense for that deployment model.

Answer (score 3):

There is no support for domains in Cloudhub as the deployment model there is 1 Mule Runtime - 1 Mule application, so shared resources would have no impact.

Answer (score 0):

Domains would work in standalone mule runtime where applications can share resources .In Cloudhub,each application would run in its own mule runtime ,hence resource sharing is not feasible